# Finding and removing the last occurrence of a specified element in a list [racket]

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I've started to write a function that should find the last occurrence of an element in a list. My idea was to use `search` to count the occurrences of the specified symbol and return it. I would then pass the count into `removeLast` that would remove the element. I would then decrement the count in `removeLast` to facilitate the base case.  From what I've been seeing using `set!` is generally bad practice. Is there a better/more elegant way to "remember" the last occurrence of symbol.

```
(define (lastLess lis symbol)
  (define count 0)
   (set! count (search symbol lis count))
  (removeLast symbol lis count)
)

(define (search symbol lis count )
  ( cond ((null? lis) count)
     ( (eq? symbol (car lis)) (+ count (add1 (search symbol (cdr lis) count ))) )
     ( (pair? (car lis))(+ count(+ 0 (search symbol (car lis) count ))))
     ( else (+ count(+ 0 (search symbol (cdr lis) count))))
     )
)

(define (removeLast symbol lis count)
  (cond ((null? lis) '())
    ((eq? count 0) (cdr lis))
    ((eq? symbol (car lis)) ((set! count (sub1 count)) 
                             (cons (car lis)(removeLast symbol (cdr lis) count))
                            )
                            )
    ((pair? (car lis)) (removeLast symbol (car lis) count))
    (else (cons (car lis) (removeLast symbol (cdr lis) count )))
    )
)
```

Running the code as is the `((set! count (sub1 count))(cons (car lis)(removeLast symbol (cdr lis) count))))` throws an error:

> application: not a procedure;
>   expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
>    given: #
>    arguments...:
>     '(e)

EDIT: This is an assignment for class, so redundant `reverse`s aren't acceptable, and I must account for nest lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are experiences are from the `cond` clause. You have extra parenthesis around (set! count ...).

Your problem is your obsession with set!
This:

```
(define (lastLess lis symbol)
  (define count 0)
  (set! count (search symbol lis count))
  (removeLast symbol lis count))
```

Could have been done

```
(define (lastLess lis symbol)
  (removeLast symbol lis (search symbol lis 0)))
```

or I you want assignment, which is good when using the result more than one place

```
(define (lastLess lis symbol)
  (let ((count (search symbol lis 0)))
    (if (< 0 count) ; noe or more occurences
        (removeLast symbol lis count)
        lis)))
```

Your search procedure will start following lists in lists without finishing with the list it is in. each for a in `(a b (c d b) a b)` your procedure will return 2 and not 3. + can have any number of arguments so you don't need to nest them. Try this:

```
(define (search symbol lis count)
  (cond ((null? lis) count)
     ((eq? symbol (car lis)) (search symbol (cdr lis) (add1 count)))
     ((pair? (car lis)) (search symbol (cdr lis)
                                (search symbol (car lis) count)))
     (else (search symbol (cdr lis) count))))
```

Notice how pairs are handled. Now your removeLast shouldn't jump over whatever it gets when count is zero but when symbol matches and count is 1.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You should use built-in procedures for this. In particular, notice that `remove` deletes the *first* element of `lis` that is equal to `symbol`, so removing the *last* element is a simple matter of reversing the list:

```
(define (lastLess lis symbol)
  (reverse (remove symbol (reverse lis))))

(lastLess '(1 2 3 4 5 1) 1)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

The above solution doesn't require at all using `set!`, which as you suspect, is not recommended - although it's possible to solve this problem mutating the list, a functional solution is preferred in Scheme.

Of course, a more efficient solution could be written, one that only traverses the list once, but ask yourself: do you really need the added complexity of such a solution? is a high performance so important? if the answer is no, then stick to a simpler, clearer solution.

Comment: Now would that also take nested lists into account?  This is an assignment for class and my professor said that "redundant reverses are not acceptable." I do appreciate your input.

Comment: This answer was posted before the edit, and no - it doesn't take into account nested lists and indeed it's performing a couple of (redundant?) reverses. After your edit, the question is a completely different (and harder) beast. Sorry, I can't look for an answer now, it's well past midnight around here :)

Answer (score 0):

This still uses set, but is a more elegant solution I would argue, as the set is used within a closure of an anonymous function that you pass as an argument as foldr. After if finds the first match (remember working from the tail, it inactivates itself to work as a cons.  Since foldr works from the tail end of the list there is no extra traversal required. make-remover is a functional process (one input will always map to the same output) however the output is non-function, but it's not so much of a problem as you only use it once and throw it away. (and you don't wan the one-to-one mapping anyways)

```
(define (remove-last x L)
 (let ((proc (make-remover x)))
  (foldr proc '() L)))


(define (make-remover removee)
 (let ((active? #t))
  (lambda (x y)
   (cond ((not active?) (cons x y))
         ((eq? x removee) (begin (set! active? #f) y))
         (else (cons x y))))))
```

this won't traverse a tree (work on nested lists) but it shouldn't be terrible difficult to modify foldr to a foldr-tree that will foldr on sublists before applying the procedure to them.